# how to tell the diffrence among the following expressions?

Tags: difference, causative-have, causative-get

The following pairs of expressions seem to have the same meaning in general. The active group means "to persuade or force sb to do sth" in LONGMAN dictionary, and their passive version means "sth have been done". Are they actually different in terms of usage, style or meaning?

A:

> have sb do / have sb doing / get sb doing

B:

> have sth done / get sth done

Comment: The ***get*** versions aren't the same. *I'll **get** it done tomorrow* might mean *I'll **have** [someone else] do tomorrow*, but it might equally carry the sense of *I **will do it** [myself] [by] tomorrow*. As to ***have sb do / have sb doing***, that mostly depends on whether you're talking about a planned future action or something that's ***currently ongoing*** (but of course there are things like *I'll be having s/b fixing my car tomorrow*, so nothing is that "fixed").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> X has Y done

is **NOT** a passive form; it is a perfect form. It specifies the actor, namely X, and further indicates that the action Y was completed prior to the time of utterance.

> X has Z doing Y

means that X arranged in the past for Z to complete action Y in the future.

This is the causative usage of “have.”

So no, the two expressions do not have the same meaning.